# How to create subdomain in Nginx server on ubuntu 14.04 in DigitalOcean?

Tags: nginx, subdomain, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to create subdomain for my blogging site in digitalocean. I have added a cname record in my domain section. Subdomain is showing in the zone file. I have created file named blog in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and added the following lines-

```
server {
   listen  80;
   server_name blog.deshipro.com;
   location / {
          root   /usr/share/nginx/blog;
          index index.php index.html index.html;
   }
}
```

And also added `include /etc/nginx/sites/enabled/*;` in my `nginx.conf` file. I also added a symbolic link -

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/blog /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/blog
```

Restarted server. But still it shows "This site can’t be reached." Pinging also not working as well. If the host is resolved. then pinging it should get an ip [There is an ip in zone file against the subdomain]. So, what am I missing? I'm new to digitalocean, and tried every possible tutorials they have. No luck at all. Can somebody help? Really stuck here for two days.

Comment: Where did you create the cname? Did you create it in the DNS control panel on Digital Ocean?

Comment: Yes, from the DNS control panel on Digital Ocean.

Comment: That is why it doesn't work. You have at some point transferred the DNS for the domain to cloudflare. You need to manage your DNS there.

Comment: Can you provide some link/material to follow on, or something more details, please? I'm quite new at these stuffs. By the way, thanks for helping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46754/discussion-between-h-jabi-and-drifter104).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me break this down a little.

The domain **deshipro.com** is registered with **GODADDY.COM**

The site is hosted on **DigitalOcean**

The DNS is managed by **Cloudflare**

Each one of those services offers and provides DNS management services. In this case you have registered the CloudFlare domain servers, within the GoDaddy control panel. This is absolutely fine, what this does is tell any client that comes looking for your site to go and ask the CloudFlare servers for the information.

So the fact you have configured the `CNAME` at DigitalOcean in this case doesn't do anything. As no clients will ask there for the information.

What you need to do is use the following guides.

If DigitalOcean have told you your site as located at a particular IP address, then follow the following guide and create and `A Record` for `blog.deshipro.com`
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169096-How-do-I-add-A-records-

If DigitalOcean have told you site is located at `something.digitalocean.com` then follow the following guide and create a `cname` `blog.deshipro.com` > `something.digitalocean.com` (*It won't actually be something.digitalocean.com*)
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169046-How-do-I-add-a-CNAME-record-